# opencv python cv2.line works only for certain pixel values

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter

[Result image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkTHD.png)

I am using `cv2.line` to draw vertical lines across my image. The command works for certain values of pixels but not for all of them. For example I can draw a line through pixels (21,1) to (21,450) but not through  (160,1) to (160,450). I am sure my image is larger than 160 pixels. I have used different values and it seems random to me in which values the line is printed and in which values it is not. Here is my code (I am working with Jupiter notebook):

```
new_im = cv2.cvtColor(edge, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.line(new_im,(21,1),(21,450),(255,0,0),1)
cv2.line(new_im,(50,1),(50,450),(255,0,0),1)
cv2.line(new_im,(100,1),(100,450),(255,0,0),1)
cv2.line(new_im,(150,1),(150,450),(255,0,0),1)
cv2.line(new_im,(155,1),(155,450),(255,0,0),1)
cv2.line(new_im,(165,1),(165,450),(255,0,0),1) 
plt.imshow(new_im)
plt.show()
```

I have also tried to change the order of the lines but I get the same result. Some lines are printed and some are not.

Comment: can you post an image with the _wrong_ result?

Comment: What is `new_im.shape`?

Comment: @w-m the output is (490, 190, 3)

Comment: @Miki 
![new_image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lifZXkd2FVZZBomS0nUmfoxvQ40I9Zpz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Miki that was actually the output to:

    new_im = cv2.cvtColor(edge, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

    cv2.line(new_im,(21,1),(21,450),(255,0,0),1)

    cv2.line(new_im,(50,1),(50,450),(255,0,0),1)

    cv2.line(new_im,(100,1),(100,450),(255,0,0),1)

    cv2.line(new_im,(150,1),(150,450),(255,0,0),1)
    cv2.line(new_im,(155,1),(155,450),(255,0,0),1)
    cv2.line(new_im,(165,1),(165,450),(255,0,0),1)
    plt.imshow(new_im)
    plt.show()

Comment: @ReynaRamírez please upload the image directly to the post (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) the Google Drive link is not publicly accesible. And update the example code in the post as well, it's hard to parse the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imshow [defaults](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow) to nearest neighbor interpolation in some backends.

If the view is smaller than the original image, some rows may be dropped and not displayed at all.

Fix it by explicitly setting an appropriate interpolation string, e.g. bilinear:

```
plt.imshow(new_im, interpolation="bilinear")
```